# Issue with Microsoft Edge URL parameters with URL Encoding %3A

Tags: microsoft-edge, url-encoding, url-parameters

I have the following problem with Microsoft edge browser. When using 22%3A11 in URL parameter as value, then the browser don't send it as shown in url, but will send it modified as %E2%80%8E22%3A11%E2%80%8E.

With Google Chrome i dont have this issue.

Does anybody know why Microsoft Edge is sending it modified? Instead of sending it as it shown on the URL field?

Comment: Searching for "%E2%80%8E" brings up plenty of hits, many on StackOverflow even.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in edge (https://urldecode.org/?text=22%253A11&mode=decode) - can you share a link where it can be reproduced?